# How to set Backgound color of a button programmatically using BackgroundTint and using as background @android:color/holo_orange_light

Tags: android, android-button

I want to put a background tint in a button for android versions newer than lollipop so I do

```
MyButton.setBackgroundTintList(ContextCompat.getColor(this, HOW TO PASS THE COLOR HERE?));
```

but How to pass the color of @android:color/holo_orange_light ? this color belongs to theme?

thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to add android color in your color resources, you can do it like that:

```
button.getBackground().setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(this, android.R.color.holo_orange_light), PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
```